# Plotting N number of Graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
               spot      total
date_delivery       
2016-06-21       x            20
2016-07-25       x            22
2016-08-14       x            25
2016-09-11       y            16
2016-10-16       y            10
```

The index of the DataFrame is in a `datetime` format. I want to create a simple graph for each unique spot that shows the total over time. I am having trouble writing a loop that performs this as well as saves each one. Keep in mind that while there is only 2 actual `spots` in this DataFrame the real one has many many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append spot to the index, groupby spot and then plot

```
df.set_index('spot', append=True).groupby(level='spot').plot(kind='bar')
```

For your example you'll get two bar graphs, one for x, one for y, right below each other (but you can customize that)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. How would I save all of them without doing it manually?

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, then `plt.savefig('myfig.jpg')` for example. Pretty sure you'll have to loop over your groupby object in order to save each individually.